Ubuntu 24.04 LTS installation does not finish in VirtualBox
I tried to use a Linux virtual machine for the very first time. So I downloaded the VirtualBox and the Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. I found some tutorials how should I finish this process. Everything went well untill the intallation process, it started intalling but its never finished. Now it runs for almos 40 minutes, is it normal? I just see this:

Please somebody help me!
I gave for cpu and 8gb of ram and 25 gb storage, my computer is not slow(imo)

As the Microsoft's document said:

Many third-party virtualization applications don't work together with Hyper-V. Affected applications include VMware Workstation and VirtualBox. These applications might not start virtual machines, or they may fall back to a slower, emulated mode.

So you may improve your host environment for Ubuntu 24.04 by these steps:

Get and install the latest VirtualBox
Restart your computer and check the CPU settings in BIOS: Intel VT-x or AMD-V should be enabled
Last but the most important: disable Hyper-V with the following command in an elevated PowerShell prompt:

  Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-Hypervisor


The same issue occurred for me. I opened the terminal to check the process and saw that it was still running but taking a long time to download packages. Upon inspecting the VM's network settings, I realized it was set to NAT. After switching it to a Bridged Adapter, the process sped up and completed within a few minutes.

It finally finished after 1 hour, I discovered a small button in the righ bottom corner where you can see the processes, and I saw that it still installing. Use this small button if you thing the process is stopped, maybe its not:)

That small button looks like a small icon of a terminal. Click this icon to see what is currently running in the terminal. Ubuntu can take a long time to install if you select the full installation including media codecs and drivers and also downloading updates while installing.
